# Jmeter Mobile app not recording with Proxy setting

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, blazemeter

J-meter version 2.12 and 2.13

OS windows : Windows 7

Android version 4.4

NOTE:Mobile app is our test environment and still under testing phase

J meter recording:
When I set the proxy then the app is not recording in j meter i.e. Am not able

to login to the app itself.

However if I remove the proxy setting then am able to login to app successfully

and can perform the transactions

I tried with the app which are their in play store , most of the app are

recorded with proxy setting

So am a having doubt due to signed apk then the app is recording in j meter are what ?

Am not able to figure whats the problem is . Can anybody please help me.

Our Plan is to record the mobile transactions through j-meter and upload the script to Blaze meter

Thanks,
Prabhakar.Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may be using HTTPS and Android native network configuration utility may not support HTTPS proxying so the options are:

1. Perform additional configuration:

   - Use third-party application like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) which supports HTTPS proxying
   - Install JMeter's `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` (it's generated in /bin folder of JMeter installation) onto device
2. Use [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service instead.